# how to call delete on an object that was allocated in the parameter for a constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have two classes, one inherits from `ostream` and the other inherits from `streambuf` and this is how i am using them

```
int main () {
   stampstream ss(8,10);
}
```

**Stampstream**

```
stampstream::stampstream(int r, int c) : ostream(new stampbuf(r,c))
{
   std::cout << "I am in stampstream" << std::endl;
}
```

I am just calling the parent (ostream) class ctor and creating an object of stampbuf class in the parameter.

**Stampbuf**

```
stampbuf::stampbuf(int r, int c)
: _row(0), _column(0), BUFFER_SIZE(10), _buffer(new char[BUFFER_SIZE]) 
{ //some code }
```

so when I run Valgrind on my project it says i have 106 bytes of memory leak. 96 of which is coming from `new stampbuf(r,c)` and 10 from `_buffer(new char[BUFFER_SIZE])`

I have destructor for stampbuf which calls `delete` on `_buffer` to release the memory. However the destructor is never being called. How do I get rid of this memory leak and call the destructor for stampbuf?

**Edit**

```
class stampstream : public ostream {

public:
stampstream(int r, int c);
virtual ~stampstream();
};

class stampbuf : public streambuf {

 public:
stampbuf(int r, int c);
~stampbuf();
virtual int overflow(int ch);
    };
```

Comment: can you post full example? for example, you are missing the code for destructor

Comment: You should probably call your `stampbuf*` data member something other than `ostream`, to avoid potential clashes with `std::ostream`.

Comment: it is not a variable of type stampbuf, it is the std::ostream constructor that takes an argument of any class that inherits `std::streambuf`. In my case, `stampbuf` inherits from `std::streambuf`

Answer (score 5):

You need to call

```
delete ostream;
```

in the destructor of `stampstream` and

```
delete[] _buffer;
```

in the destructor of `stampbuf`.

**You're better off using `std::unique_ptr` for `ostream`, a `std::vector` for `_buffer`**, and you wouldn't need to worry about memory management. Also, `ostream` is a name in `std`, I suggest you rename your variable before it's too late.

Comment: @BoPersson that's the name of the variable. `stampbuf` is the type.

Comment: `ostream` is not a variable name, it is the `std::ostream`, I am calling the constructor of `std::ostream` in the initialization list.

Comment: @SherCoder are you by any change inheriting from `std::ostream`? Maybe you should post the relevant parts of your `stampstream` class declaration.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, I have mentioned that in my post.

Comment: @SherCoder with the syntax you have now, `ostream` is a member name.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it can also be a base class constructor. That caught me out too.

Comment: @SherCoder don't inherit from `std` classes. Use composition instead.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yeah you're right but for this project sake, I have to do it this way.

Comment: @SherCoder then see Bjarke's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it as follows:

```
stampstream::~stampstream()
{
    delete rdbuf();
}
```

However, this is not safe. Since the user of `stampstream` could (and has the right to) change the `rdbuf`, it may cause undefined behavior.

The idiomatic way is to have the corresponding `streambuf` a member of your `ostream` derived class, thus avoiding any dynamic memory allocation.

```
class stampstream : public ostream {
public:
    // ...
private:
    stampbuf sb;
};

stampstream::stampstream(int r, int c) : ostream(&sb)
{
    // ...
}

// nothing to delete in the destructor...
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that ostream does not clean up the stream buffer in its destructor:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/~ostream/

> [...] Note that it does not destroy nor performs any operations on the
>   associated streambuf object.

So you have to clean up the streambuf somewhere else. The easiest thing is to make your stampbuf object a member variable of stampstream - then its destructor gets called automatically when your stampstream is destructed.

The constructor of the base class ostream gets called before member variables get constructed, so the constructor of ostream ends up looking at an unconstructed stampbuf object if you pass the stampbuf object as a parameter to the ostream constructor. So instead do not pass the stream buffer to the constructor, set it inside the constructor, after the stampbuf has been construct using rdbuf:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/

This presents the problem that your stampbuf gets destructed before the base class does, so the destructor of ostream is going to be looking at a deconstructed stampbuf. That is normally unacceptable, but since the page for ~ostream above guarantees that ~ostream does not do anything with the stream buffer, it is fine in this case.

Comment: @BoPersson Interesting. Is it guaranteed by the standard that ostream::ostream does nothing with the passed in buffer, or is this just something that happens to work on some (or even all current) implementations? [This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/ostream/) does not specify such a guarantee, but of course that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: The standard would say that the constructor does not touch the buffer precisely in order to allow the technique that you are suggesting. The same reason it specifies that the destructor does not touch the buffer (if cplusplus.com can be trusted). If you compile on another std library or even the next minor revision of your current standard library, it would be conforming for that upgrade to crash your program if there is no language in the standard to allow passing in an unconstructed buffer. Is there any advantage to outweigh the risk here?

Comment: I bet the standard does not require the passed-in buffer to be not constructed, so I don't know how it is relevant that fstream and stringstream have to pass in their buffers? For example if you use multiple inheritance and privately derive from the buffer you can make the buffer be constructed first, or you could call new and get the buffer constructed first that way. There is no reason that I can see that std::fstream would need to pass in an unconstructed buffer.

Comment: "The standard would say..." nope. This goes the other way around. The implementation of the standard library must behave as if it does exactly what the standard says it does. So it cannot assume anything that the standard does not say it can assume. Therefore as long as your program does not violating anything in the description in the standard it must work with any standard conforming implementation (otherwise such implementation would not be standard conforming).

Comment: @ybungalobill I think your point is that ostream needs to be allowed by the standard to call methods on the buffer. I would assume that the ostream is allowed to call methods on the buffer since otherwise it cannot use the buffer at all. The question is if the language allowing ostream to call methods on the buffer is specified in a way that rules out calling those methods in the constructor. I don't know the answer to that - I made it a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931999/is-it-safe-to-pass-an-unconstructed-buffer-to-the-constructor-of-stdostream).